# Calculate the circuit time constant, the supply current after 2 seconds and the capacitor voltage after 3 seconds?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, dc, circuits

[image]

So far I have answered a and b however I am not sure if and when to convert the units to SI and what unit of measurement we leave our final answer. And if I have made any mistakes on the way please point them out.

2a) Time constant= RC
Hence, =50 x  10^{-6}  . 20,000= 1, do we say our final answer in seconds or milliseconds as I have converted the initial resistor and capacitor values?

b) let i=I(e^-t/RC) Where I=V/R

```
Therefore, I=50/20,000= 2.5 x 10^{-3}, is the final unit of measurement Amps or milliamps and why?
```

i= 2.5 x {10^-3}(e^{-2000/1000})

i= 3.38 x {10^{-4}  what is the final unit of measurement here

c) Capacitor voltage= V(1-e^{-t/RC})
Vc= 100(1-e^{-3/1})= 95.02

EDIT:

I have made a mistake on part b regarding I=V/R

the values should be 100/20 which should give the answer as 5A or 5000mA

i= 5(e^{-2/1})

i=0.067A

Comment: Use the provided math tool for entering equations. Much easier to read.

Comment: Looks like you are on track. Check your substitution of values.

Comment: You were right the first time. Initial current is \$\frac{100V}{20000\Omega}=5mA\$

Answer (score 2):

> do we say our final answer in seconds or milliseconds

1 second and 1000 milliseconds are two ways to say the exact same thing. Unless your instructor has a neurotic condition about the best way to express these measurements you should get full marks for either way of expressing the answer.

> is the final unit of measurement Amps or milliamps

Again, \$2.5\times10^{-3}\ {\rm A}\$ and 2.5 mA are two ways to say the exact same thing. Unless your instructor has given very explicit instructions about when to use one or the other, you shouldn't be penalized for using either one.

Even if you answered \$2.5\times10^{-9}\ {\rm MA}\$, it would be reasonable to say you deliberately chose to use an inconvenient unit to express the answer just to be confusing, but in the context of an exam I'd say the answer is still technically correct and should get full marks (Your instructor might not agree with me).

Comment: Yes sometimes my instructor wants the SI units immediately converted sometimes he wants it towards the end of the final answer, but the unit has to be correct for full marks.

Comment: @AckimNkole, amperes and milliamperes are both SI units. Seconds and milliseconds are both SI units. If your instructor has given specific instructions about when to use seconds and when to use milliseconds, you need to follow those instructions, but since none of us know what those instructions are, we can't advise you on how to do that beyond saying you should follow your instructor's instructions.

Comment: thank you for clarifying the SI units

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help. All the following are SI units of time:

$$ \text{ns, μs, ms, s, ks, Ms, Gs} $$

The "metric prefixes" \$\text{n, μ, m, k, M, G}\$ don't change that fact, since they are just scaling factors of \$10^{-9}, 10^{-6}, 10^{-3}, 10^{3}, 10^{6}, 10^{9}\$ respectively. It's the "\$\text{s}\$" that makes it an SI unit.

You may be forgiven for converting large quantities of seconds into minutes or hours, such as quoting \$1.5\text{ hours}\$ instead of \$5400\text{ s}\$, but just be aware that \$\text{hour}\$, \$\text{minute}\$, \$\text{day}\$ etc are *not* SI units. It is common to convert to and quote \$\text{hours}\$, \$\text{minutes}\$, \$\text{days}\$ etc instead of using the prefixes \$\text{k}\$, \$\text{M}\$, \$\text{G}\$.

It's rare to see long durations or time constants written as \$18.5\text{ ks}\$ or \$5\text{ Ms}\$, but there is *absolutely nothing wrong* with these expressions of SI units. If you are explicitly requested to stick to SI units, *do not convert* to \$\text{hours}\$, \$\text{minutes}\$, \$\text{days}\$ and so on.

Very few other SI units have an equivalent of "minutes" or "hours", and so you'd never quote, say, a voltage in any other form than \$\text{V}\$ alone, or prefixed with a multiplier like \$\text{μ}\$ or \$\text{k}\$.

It's common to quote values less than 1 without a scaling metric prefix or exponent, but the more zeros there are following the decimal place, the harder it is to read:

| Value | Preferred | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \$0.15\text{ s}\$ |  | No problem here |
| \$0.015\text{ A}\$ | \$15\text{ mA}\$ | Either is fine, but the use of m is recommended |
| \$0.0015\text{ V}\$ | \$1.5\text{ mV}\$ | Starts getting confusing, definitely use the m prefix |
| \$0.00015\text{ s}\$ | \$150 \text{ μs}\$ | Don't ever quote three zeros or more after the decimal point |

Similarly, large numbers can be hard to read when the number of digits to the left of the decimal place is too great, so the use of metric prefixes is strongly encouraged:

| Value | Preferred | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \$150\text{ s}\$ |  | No problem here |
| \$1500\text{ A}\$ | \$1.5\text{ kA}\$ | Either is fine, but the use of k is recommended |
| \$15000\text{ Ω}\$ | \$15\text{ kΩ}\$ | Starts getting confusing, definitely use the k prefix |
| \$150000\text{ Ω}\$ | \$150\text{ kΩ}\$ | Don't ever quote five digits or more, use a metric prefix |

Every value is those tables is an SI unit, your only concern is to make the quantity readable. Those metric prefixes are a huge help, so always use them when appropriate, and practice using them as much as possible.

Use of a metric prefix does not alter the fact that a unit is SI.

Comment: The SI unit symbols (mA, mV, etc) should **not** be italicized and there should be a space between the quantity and the symbol.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson That's just mathjax. Know a way to unitalicise it all? Maybe \text{}?

Comment: Yes, I fixed one of the tables.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Fixed the rest